# Firebase Cloud Messaging Single Device Failed Status

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-notifications

I'm trying to implement push notifications for my Android app through Firebase. When I target an entire user segment, I immediately receive the notification on my device. However, when I target a single device I never receive the notification and see a failed status in the Firebase console.

I'm getting the FCM registration token when the user signs in to my app using

```
 FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
```

and I added

```
 compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:10.0.1'
```

to my build.gradle file.

I saw that the documentation recommends extending `FirebaseInstanceIdService` and overriding `onTokenRefresh()`, but I'm thinking that the token doesn't change from the moment I log in to 10 seconds later when I send the push notification from the Firebase console.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: Hi. Can you add in your code snippets? Also, can you provide more details on the message you're sending via the Firebase console? What the error looks like and what message details you're sending would be helpful. Cheers! :)

Comment: you could try to send the message to the token via HTTP api and see the actual error. Otherwise please contact firebase support to investigate the issue.